# overloading assignment operator doesn't work with chaining

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I wanted to make a dimension check before assigning new values. So I did this:

**Matrix.cpp**

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(Matrix m){      

    // check dimensions
    if(m_rows != m.m_rows || m_cols != m.m_cols )
        fail();

    thrust::copy(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), m.d_data.begin() );// gives error if pass in Matrix& m
    return *this;
}
```

**Matrix.h**

```
Matrix& operator=(Matrix m);
```

**test.cpp**

```
Matrix A, B;
... initialize B as all 1's ...
A = B;       // This works
A = B * 3.0; // Wrong, A = B
B = B * 3.0; // Wrong, B does not change
```

If operator = is not overloaded, it is correct:

```
Matrix A, B;
... initialize B as all 1's ...
A = B;       // A is all 1's
A = B * 3.0; // A is all 3's
B = B * 3.0; // B is all 3's
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're copying the wrong way.

```
thrust::copy(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), m.d_data.begin() );
```

Should be:

```
thrust::copy(m.d_data.begin(), m.d_data.end(), d_data.begin() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your copy is backwards. You are copying from the current object into the parameter `m`, which was passed by value. The copied data is destroyed along with the parameter when the function returns, so it effectively does nothing.

This would have been revealed as a const correctness error if you had passed a canonical `const &` argument instead of by value.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out from this, this might be helpful:

http://www.programmingtunes.com/overloading-assignment-operator-in-c/

this is the blog where i got the solution, you might also find your answer